# Help Explaining Sequence Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to wrap my head around the following definition:

> The sequence $p_1, p_2, p_3, ...$ converges to the point $x$ if the following is true. For every open interval $(a,b)$ containing $x$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that $p_n \in (a,b)$ for every positive integer $n$ greater than $N$.

Can someone explain how this relates to the following definition?

> A sequence $p_n$ converges to the point $x$ if for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a number $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that $|p_n-x|<\varepsilon$

Both definitions should be saying the same thing, but I don't understand them to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The second statement is a specialization of the first statement, restricting attention only to $(a,b)=(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ for each $\varepsilon > 0$. So naively, the second statement seems weaker than the first. However, any open interval containing $x$ must contain $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$. So in fact the two are equivalent.

Comment: I think I understand the equivalence. I am still a little lost, however, on where $|p_n-x|<\varepsilon$ comes from...

Comment: @anon1 $|p_n-x|<\varepsilon$ is exactly the same as $p_n \in (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$. Try drawing a picture to see this. The point is that $|p_n-x|$ is the (absolute) distance from $p_n$ to $x$.

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense. Not sure why I didn't see it.